# ExactTarget: Open Rate Breakdown for Triggered Send based upon specific column

Tags: marketing-cloud, send-email

I have set up a TriggeredSend that populates a data extension with several fields. One of the fields is a clientId, and another field is the url of an image the corresponds to the client represented by the clientId. I will essentially be sending the same email, with different images, depending upon the client sponsoring the email.

When pulling the tracking data for the triggered send, i'm able to see the open and click rates for the triggered send as a whole. I would like to understand the click rate for each client, which is easily distinguished in my email via the clientId.

How can I report on the open rates for each unique clientId in my data extension?

Any help would be appreciated.

One solution I can see is to have 2 different TriggeredSends, however as I obtain more and more clients, this doesn't scale so easily.

Any help would be appreciated!